# How Can I store city name obtained from geolocation to a variable and send ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, vue.js

```
<script>
      new Vue({ 
    el: '#fad' , 
    data: { 
      data: {}, 
    }, 
    mounted() { 
       var self = this;

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
      function success(position) {
        var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';
        $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
        $('#country').html(location.results[0].address_components[5].long_name);
          $('#state').html(location.results[0].address_components[4].long_name);
          $('#city').html(location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name);
          $('#address').html(location.results[0].formatted_address);
          $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
          $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
        })

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api/post//',
          data: {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lon: position.coords.longitude,
            city:location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name,
          },
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (e) { 
            if (e.status == 1) { 
              self.data = e.data; 
              console.log(e.data) 
            }
          }
        });
        console.log(lat);
      }

      function error(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

This is my code. I am able to get lat and lon values and pass. But I am not able to pass city. When I do this way, I am getting error. I am very weak in js and this is the first time doing a project. Please help me to obtain the result. I need to send name of city through ajax request. `<span id="city"></city>` in html gives me the city name. How to get the city name in script and send this by ajax request. Please help me?

Comment: What is your error message showing?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at success

Comment: this is coming sir

Comment: Here you cannot get location out side of this function
$.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {

   //AJAX here

});
Write AJAX function inside the callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you were trying to make the AJAX function in the wrong place. The `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous so the response is not necessarily available immediately - thus the ajax request that you are trying to send should be sent only on getting the response from `getCurrentPosition`

```
<script>
    new Vue({ 
        el: '#fad' , 
        data: { 
            data: {}, 
        },
        mounted(){

            var self = this;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, error );


            function success( position ) {/* geolocation success callback */
                var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';
                $.getJSON( GEOCODING ).done( function( location ) {

                    $('#country').html(location.results[0].address_components[5].long_name);
                    $('#state').html(location.results[0].address_components[4].long_name);
                    $('#city').html(location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name);
                    $('#address').html(location.results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
                    $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);


                    /*

                        As this is an asynchronous process, make the 
                        ajax request here.

                    */
                    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    console.log( lat );

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://api/post//',
                        data: {
                            lat: position.coords.latitude,
                            lon: position.coords.longitude,
                            city: location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name,
                            state: location.results[0].address_components[4].long_name,
                            country: location.results[0].address_components[5].long_name
                        },
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(e) { 
                            if( e.status == 1 ) { 
                                self.data = e.data; 
                                console.log( e.data ) 
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            function error( err ) {/* geolocation error callback */
                console.log( err )
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code, that's why it's not running.

In your $.ajax call, you have a semicolon after

`city:location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;`

which is a syntax error, remove the trailing `;`

## EDIT

You updated your answer and fixed the trailing `;`, next to that the code seems to run ok, check the snippet below.

Here's a small snippet with reformatted code. Don't forget to change your `$.ajax` url, unless you really want to POST to `https://api/post`

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#fad',
    data: {
        data: {},
    },
    mounted() {
        var self = this;

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function () {


                var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';

                $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function (location) {
                    $('#country').html(location.results[0].address_components[5].long_name);
                    $('#state').html(location.results[0].address_components[4].long_name);
                    $('#city').html(location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name);
                    $('#address').html(location.results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
                    $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api/post//',
                    data: {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lon: position.coords.longitude,
                        city: location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name,
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (e) {
                        if (e.status == 1) {
                            self.data = e.data;
                            console.log(e.data)
                        }
                    }
                });


            },
            function () {

            });

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="fad"></div>
```

Comment: sorry sir, after i changed the same. i get the error as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at success